# Passing a string from view to controller in ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got an ASP.NET MVC Razor application. In this application I have a MultiSelect  control (which is basically a dropdown you can select multiple items from). I have subscribed to the "close" event of this control so that when it is closed, it passes a string of comma separated integers into the controller. However, although the method in the controller is being called, the value being passed into is always null. I have tested the event and I know that the string is being generated correctly. Here is the code in the event handler:

```
    `function close() {
        var alertTypeIds = $("#alertMultiSelect").val().toString();
        //alert("this is the alertTypeId: " + alertTypeIds);
        $.post('@Url.Action("SubscribeToAlerts")', { value: alertTypeIds }, function (result) {
            alert("the value was successfully sent to the server");
        });
    };`
```

Here is the controller code:

```
`public void SubscribeToAlerts(string alertTypeIds)
    {
        bool isSubscribedToNewItem = false;
        bool isSubscribedToNewCustomer = false;
        bool isSubscribedToNewSupplier = false;

        if (alertTypeIds.Contains('1')){
            isSubscribedToNewItem = true;
        }
        if (alertTypeIds.Contains('2')) {
            isSubscribedToNewCustomer = true;
        }
        if (alertTypeIds.Contains('3')) {
            isSubscribedToNewSupplier = true;
        }

        var subscriptionRepository = new BMTool.Persistance.SubscriptionRepository();
        var userRepository = new BMTool.Persistance.UserRepository();

        IList<BMTool.Models.User> user = userRepository.GetUser("anorkin@daymon.com");
        int associateId = user[0].AssociateId;

        subscriptionRepository.UpdateSubscriptionForUser(associateId, isSubscribedToNewItem, isSubscribedToNewCustomer, isSubscribedToNewSupplier,
            isSubscribedToBmTerminated, isSubscribedToBmChange, isSubscribedToItemCategoryChange);
    }`
```

Now I know that the string alertTypeIds is being generated correctly in the handler. I also know that the controller method is being hit. However, the value being passed into the controller (alertTypeIds) is always null. I also want to note that I am aware that this is sloppy code. I just wanted to make sure that I'm not passing in a null before I go through the work of writing code I may have to throw away.

Answer (score 3):

It would have to be this instead; notice the new data name:

```
 $.post('@Url.Action("SubscribeToAlerts")', { alertTypeIds: alertTypeIds }, 
     function (result) {
            alert("the value was successfully sent to the server");
     });
```

The name of the field needs to match the name in the controller, so you have to use alertTypeIds.